# Is possible to store firebase data & run the application functions in offline mode in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, store, angularfire2

I found some tutorials about offline mode firebase for Ionic 2 but still I don't know how can I enable this thing in my application.

So, Is firebase realy support offline mode? If yes, **can I store all recieved data** and **run the functions in offline mode**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official support yet from firebase.But you can do that using [**angularfire2-offline**](https://github.com/adriancarriger/angularfire2-offline) library.

> A simple wrapper for AngularFire2 to read and write to Firebase while
>   offline, even after a complete refresh.

Here is a great article about it: [**Offline Sync With AngularFire2**](https://javebratt.com/offline-angularfire2/)

[**Ionic Offline Tutorial**](https://github.com/adriancarriger/angularfire2-offline/tree/master/examples/ionic#ionic-offline-tutorial-)

Comment: Thank u so much my friend, 2nd link solved my problem 

Comment: It's my pleasure :)