# Does Ionic Firebase have the same features as native?

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic4

I was wondering if Ionic Firebase has the same features as the native Firebase. (Let's say Android). I'm especially interested in the database sync and offline features on Ionic 4. Ionic is web based of course and the Firebase web version does not have offline capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use Firebase Realtime Database in Ionic, you're using its JavaScript SDK. The regular database synchronization is implemented in all clients, so should work in Ionic too. But offline/disk persistence is not implemented in the JavaScript SDK, so won't work in Ionic.

Note that Cloud Firestore is Firebase's newest NoSQL database, and there the offline disk persistence **is** implemented in the JavaScript client too.

Also see:

- [Firebase offline capabilities in ionic / cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40448471/firebase-offline-capabilities-in-ionic-cordova)
- [Is possible to store firebase data & run the application functions in offline mode in Ionic 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596125/is-possible-to-store-firebase-data-run-the-application-functions-in-offline-mo)

Comment: Thanks! I'm already using realtime database, so for now i'd rather not use Firestore. I'm thinking about rewriting my app in either Ionic or Flutter, but your answer draws me towards Flutter.